# How do arrays with length defined by variables in C get stored in memory?

Tags: c, arrays

I have tried searching this out a lot. Static arrays are generally stored in a stack and their size is determined during compilation time.
Ex:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int array[n];
    printf("%u", sizeof(array));
    return 0;
}
```

The size of array changes for different values of n. Hence, shouldn't the array here be stored in a heap as the size is determined at run-time? Have been confused about this. Please help. Thank You!

Comment: @JoãoMendes; Why not?

Comment: You can't do this in C.  Did you try to compile this?  If you need a dynamic amount of memory, use malloc().

Comment: @OldProgrammer; Man! I think you need an update.

Comment: It works fine. I have used it a lot of times(Note: I didn't include the libraries in this snippet but it works with stdio.h).

Comment: @OldProgrammer This has been officially possible for some 16 years and counting. If you count the unofficial time of the gcc extension, you'd get closer to two decades!

Comment: `%u` isn't the right format specifier. Use `%zu` instead.

Comment: C99 supports that kind of behavior, but I don't think it'd pass any companies' code-review standards. I'd prefer using `alloca(3)` (it's usage is also frowned upon) to indicate it's a dynamic-sized variable on stack. See: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> shouldn't the array here be stored in a heap as the size is determined at run-time?

It *could*, but it is not the only way to do it. C compiler is smart enough to *defer* the allocation of memory for this variable-length array in the automatic memory (commonly known as "the stack") to the point in code where the size of the array becomes known.

In order to make this possible, a related trick for `sizeof` needed to be created. Usually, `sizeof` is evaluated at compile-time; variable-length arrays, however, changed that, requiring the `sizeof` expressions on VLAs to be evaluated at runtime. Again, the compiler provides the "enabling technology" for that by storing the actual size of your VLA in a separate hidden location in memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Just one more question. Was this made available in the later versions of gcc?

Comment: @SrikrishnaBhat `gcc` has been supporting VLAs for a very long time - I think they started before 1999, when VLAs became standard. GNU compiler also supports VLAs as an extension to C++, where they are not standard.

Comment: Learn something new (or in this case, old) every day. I stand corrected. +1

Answer (score 0):

See what standard says about this special case:

#### C11: 6.5.3.4 (p2):

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
> expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. **If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated**; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.